# Falha ao utilizar campo de pesquisa pelo Spring MVC e JpaRepository

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc

Boa tarde. Estou trabalhando em Repository e Spring MVC.
Tenho uma interface, StoreDAO que está assim.

```
public interface StoreOrderDAO extends JpaRepository<StoreOrder, String>{

List<StoreOrder> findByUser_id(String user_id);

@Query("SELECT pedido FROM StoreOrder as pedido WHERE pedido.id=:orderId AND pedido.user.id=:userId")
public StoreOrder getById(@Param("orderId") String order_id, @Param("userId") String user_id);

@Query("FROM StoreOrder s INNER JOIN s.user u WHERE u.fullname LIKE %:name%")
public Page<StoreOrder> findByName(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
```

}

Meu StoreOrderServiceImpl está assim

```
public Page<StoreOrder> getStoreOrderSearch(Integer pageNumber, String name) {
    PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1, PAGE_SIZE, Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdon");

    return storeOrderDAO.findByName(name, request);
}
```

E o StoreOrderController

```
@RequestMapping(value = {searchPath} , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(@RequestParam(value = "q", required = false) String name, ModelMap modelMap)  {

    Integer pageNumber = 1;

    Page<StoreOrder> page = storeOrderService.getStoreOrderSearch(pageNumber, name);

    int current = page.getNumber() + 1;
    int begin = Math.max(1, current - 5);
    int end = Math.min(begin + 10, page.getTotalPages());

    List<StoreOrder> orders = page.getContent();

    modelMap.addAttribute("url", getURL(defaultPath));
    modelMap.addAttribute("orders", orders);
    modelMap.addAttribute("pages", page);
    modelMap.addAttribute("beginIndex", begin);
    modelMap.addAttribute("endIndex", end);
    modelMap.addAttribute("currentIndex", current);


    return listView;
}
```

list.jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${orders}" var="row">
 <tr>
 <td><xphub:datetime value="${row.createdon}" /></td>
 <td>${row.totalamount}</td>
 <td>${row.user.fullname}</td>
 <td class="text-center"><xphub:form_actions id="${row.id}" view="true" cancel="true" /></td>
 </tr>
```

Se eu fizer uma busca pelo campo de pesquisa do sistema acontece o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "createdon"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:151)
javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:64)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:167)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:936)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp._jspx_meth_xphub_005fdatetime_005f0(list_jsp.java:458)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(list_jsp.java:414)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(list_jsp.java:260)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp.access$3(list_jsp.java:221)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp$Helper.invoke1(list_jsp.java:599)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp$Helper.invoke(list_jsp.java:627)
org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.autotag.JspModelBody.evaluate(JspModelBody.java:62)
org.apache.tiles.autotag.core.runtime.AbstractModelBody.evaluateAsString(AbstractModelBody.java:59)
org.apache.tiles.template.PutAttributeModel.execute(PutAttributeModel.java:96)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.PutAttributeTag.doTag(PutAttributeTag.java:226)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005fputAttribute_005f0(list_jsp.java:175)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp.access$0(list_jsp.java:163)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp$Helper.invoke0(list_jsp.java:577)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp$Helper.invoke(list_jsp.java:624)
org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.autotag.JspModelBody.evaluate(JspModelBody.java:62)
org.apache.tiles.autotag.core.runtime.AbstractModelBody.evaluateWithoutWriting(AbstractModelBody.java:77)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertDefinitionModel.execute(InsertDefinitionModel.java:97)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertDefinitionTag.doTag(InsertDefinitionTag.java:254)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertDefinition_005f0(list_jsp.java:158)
org.apache.jsp.presentation.views.modules.admin.store.order.list_jsp._jspService(list_jsp.java:126)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:431)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Só que se eu mandar listar os dados do banco sem passar pelo campo de pesquisa, ele retorna tudo sem erro, esse erro acontece apenas quando vou filtrar pelo campo de pesquisa.

Comment: Que taglib é essa que você esta usando? xphub? Porque pelo stacktrace o erro está na compilação de alguma jsp que está usando o value "createdon", alguma tentativa de conversão.

Answer (score 0):

Ele está tentando converter a String createdon que você setou na instanciação do objeto PageRequest para Integer e isso não é possível porque não é um número o createdon mas sim uma String com caracteres que não são números.

**EDIT**

Acabei de verificar a documentação do Spring quanto ao método que você está tentando utilizar e está correto. O createdon que você passou é um objeto do tipo String que sinaliza quais campos você quer filtrar certo? Verifique se você esta importando a classe PageRequest correta do Spring, que se encontra neste pacote: org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest. Acredito que deve estar importando a classe de um outro pacote por isto esta se perdendo.

Informações sobre a classe na documentação do Spring: http://goo.gl/Jqx74b.